# Operations workflow documentation system

Tags: windows, workflow, knowledge-organization, process-control

everyone! I'm helping a client streamline business operations, and I'd love some recommendations on software in case I'm not familiar with some options. Thanks in advance!

### The Situation

We're essentially building a manual/KB of business workflows across the organization. The manual will be used to train employees, delegate ownership, and make sure that key requirements are met. Maintaining the manual will be someone's responsibility, but users will also edit it.

### The Requirements

- Runs on Windows 7 and 10 and has at least an English localization.
- Enterprise-quality security.
- Easy to edit.
- Looks professional and slick.
- Can embed workflow diagrams, or even better, maintain them within the software.
- Revision tracking.
- Ideally: Has cross-referencing functionality that can show us which workflows are related; which workflows belong to which person/department; which workflows are tagged with certain tags; etc.
- Optional: Allows users to discuss items in the manual on some kind of separate messaging system that's linked to the manual.
- Optional: Helps automate tasks by sending out reminders, automatically creating checklists, etc.
- Optional: Stores related files.
- Optional: Cloud-based and runs on browsers.

### Other Information

- This is for an enterprise, so price isn't a huge issue. I can't say the budget, but let's assume that thousands per year would not disqualify something.
- You are a lovely person and I appreciate your help.

Comment: What you need is a BPMN software including CMS features. I'm trying to build something similar in my workplace. What I've tried so far is using Atlassian Confluence with Lucidcharts and Team Calendars addons. I don't know if it will help achieve my goals because right now I'm the only person using the solution :)